# How to add events to innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, events, innerhtml

Ok, I am adding checkboxes to an HTML form using .innerHTML statement, and I want to add an event to those checkboxes when it is clicked. Here is an example code:

```
<form id="form1">
 <fieldset>
  <select>
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
   </select>
   </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="checks"></fieldset>
</form>
```

and my script looks like this:

```
function sayHi() {
  alert("Hello!");
}

var checkb = document.getElementById("checks")
checkb.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' id='test' name='one' onclick='sayHi'>Tets One";
```

The onclick event doesnt work, I get error saying: "sayHi is not defined".

Comment: @apsillers, I concur or backslashes.

Comment: Try `onclick='sayHi();'`

Comment: Works. See [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z83NE/).

Comment: ok. it works if you do: 
document.getElementById("test").onclick = sayHi();

but if you have more than one checkbox it only works for first one. How can i make it work for all the checkboxes

Comment: @PM77-1's solution will work as long as the `sayHi` function is global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that the `sayHi` is defined in the global scope [updated based on comment], can't say exactly what's wrong without seen the entire HTML.

And you also have to change innerHTMLs inner " (double quotes) to ' (single quotes) so that it becomes a proper string.

See this fiddle and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/BuddhiP/79SMb/

Also note that when using `onclick` you need to give a executable javascript, not just a reference to a function. 
Executable JavaScript in your case is `sayHi()` with the parentheses to make it a function call rather than just a function name.

Therefore you have to say:

```
var checkb = document.getElementById("checks")
```

checkb.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' id='test' name='one' onclick='sayHi()'>Tets One";

Comment: Doesn't matter if the `sayHi` function is above or below since it's not getting invoked until the event occurs. It does however need to be global.

Comment: that's true, it needs to be global

Answer (score 2):

This is another solution, may solve your problem.
You can try from here ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W4khS/)).

```
function sayHi() {
    alert("Hello!");
}

var elem;
var checkb = document.getElementById("checks");
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    elem = document.createElement('input');
    txtElem = document.createTextNode('box');
    txtElem2 = document.createTextNode(i);
    brElem = document.createElement('br');
    elem.type = 'checkbox';
    elem.id = 'test' + i;
    elem.name = 'chk' + i;
    elem.onclick = sayHi;
    checkb.appendChild(elem);
    checkb.appendChild(txtElem);
    checkb.appendChild(txtElem2);
    checkb.appendChild(brElem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the function sayHi on `onclick` event. try adding brackets

```
<form id="form1">
    <fieldset>
        <select>
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="checks"></fieldset>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function sayHi() {
        alert("Hello");
    }

    var checkb = document.getElementById("checks")
     checkb.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" id="test" name="one" onclick="sayHi()">';

</script>
```

Make sure to keep javaScript code at the bottom of the page otherwise `document.getElementById("checks")` won't find the `checks` element

Comment: thnx i have the script in an external file

Answer (score 0):

Whay do you not use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/)?

Jquery is a great Javascript library. It'll help you to manipulate the DOM easily.
look how your code should be in Jquery style:

```
var cb = $('<input type="checkbox" id="test" name="one">').onclick(sayHi);
$("#checks").append(cb);
```